# how to unit test http request android

Tags: android, robolectric

I have used library `Robolectric` another possible framework. Http client for Android http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void getData (final ServerCallback callback) {

    client.get("http://httpbin.org/get", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            callback.onSuccess(statusCode, new String(responseBody));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            callback.onFailure(statusCode, new String(responseBody));
        }

    });
}
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ApiTest{

@Test
public void testgetData () {

}

}
```

interface

```
public interface ServerCallback {
    // Api detect connection
    void onSuccess(int statusCode, String response);
    void onFailure(int statusCode, String response);
}
```

Comment: How you tried mocking it?

Comment: I want to test how onSuccess and onFailure

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Роман,

I'll provide a general answer to get you going in the right direction.  My preferred method of testing http requests is to use the [square okhttp mockwebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp#mockwebserver).  Review the [project's unit tests](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7135628c645892faf1a48a8cff464e0ed4ad88cb/mockwebserver/src/test/java/okhttp3/mockwebserver/MockWebServerTest.java) if you have questions on their use.

In your particular case, there are a couple of things to address:

- You'll need to override the *base url* being used in tests
- The **android-async-http** library is asynchronous, however, to run a consistent unit test, you'll want the request/response to be synchronous

So, following your example, let's setup your test client as follows:

```
public class TestHttpClient {
    // package-local client that can be set in tests
    static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(); 
    // package-local baseUrl that can be set in tests
    static String baseUrl = "http://pastbin.org/";  

    public static void getData(final ServerCallback callback) {
        String url = baseUrl + "get";
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                callback.onSuccess(statusCode, new String(responseBody));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                callback.onFailure(statusCode, new String(responseBody));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To test the `TestHttpClient`, use the `MockWebServer` to spin up a server for the test and setup the client to make a request to the server:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TestHttpRequestTest {

    @Rule
    public MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

    @Test
    public void getData_onSuccess_doesSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        // Here we are creating a mock ServerCallback.  We will use
        // this mock object to verify the callback is invoked
        ServerCallback callback = mock(ServerCallback.class);

        // To test the client, we need to send a request to the mock mockWebServer.
        // The MockWebServer spins up an actual backend to handle calls.  You MUST
        // setup the client to use the base Url of the mockWebServer instead of
        // the actual url e.g.: http://httpbin.org.
        TestHttpClient.baseUrl = mockWebServer.url("/").toString();

        // For testing, use a synchronous client so that we can get the response before
        // the test completes.
        TestHttpClient.client = new SyncHttpClient();

        // Set up the mockWebServer to return a MockResponse with
        // some data in the body. This data can be whatever you want... json, xml, etc.
        // The default response code is 200.
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("success"));
        // To simulate an error
        // mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(500).setBody("error"));

        TestHttpClient.getData(callback); // calling the method under test

        verify(callback).onSuccess(200, "success"); // using verify of mockito
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The `async http client` library requires some android system components to work correctly, so you MUST use the `@RunWith(...)` annotation
- `MockWebServer` requires the `@Config(sdk = 21)` with sdk set to v21 or above to work with Robolectric.

To include the **mockwebserver & mockito** in your project, add the following to `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.2.0'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    }
```

Happy testing!!!

Comment: thanks for help... error cannot resolve method 'mock (java.long.Class)' and cannot resolve method 'verify (java.long.Class)'

Comment: `mock` & `verify` are methods from the [mockito library](http://site.mockito.org/).  I updated the additional dependencies in the answer to include mockito.